# php get file from ftp server and display save file dialog

Tags: php, ftp

I have a php page running on an apache server and a ftp server that stores the files, on a different machine. The ftp server is not accessible from outside.

I would like that when the user clicks a button on my webpage, the php server connects to the ftp server, retrieves a file, and displays a save as dialog, so that the user can store it.

Any help is appreciated,
Radu

Comment: We need code. However, on PHP's manpage for `readfile` there is a nice little download script.

Comment: Have you already had a look at [PHP’s FTP functions](http://php.net/ftp)?

Comment: What code would you need? I only called the ftp in order to retrieve the file, but I do not know how to open the save file dialog without saving the file locally.

Answer (score 1):

Here you Go.. in download.php write this

```
$file = 'location/of/your/file.ext';
readfile($file);
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file);
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

This should work :)